# Make a span float over floating div

Tags: css, asp.net, controls

In an aspx website there is the folowing construction

```
<span>TEST OVERLAY</span>
<div class="catalogItemOuter 5225" style="float: left; height: 247px; visibility: visible;">
```

I can't edit the page. I also can't edit the div, when I call the control collection of the control that creates the div the following error appears

```
 The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

Is there a way to make the contents of the span float over the contents of the div. Something with css or another way to add the control?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you have to use absolute positioning on the span and the div, with bigger z-index property for the span.

Something like that :

```css
body {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    span { 
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width : 100px;
      height: 100px;
      z-index: 2;
      background: blue;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    div {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      background: red;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<span>TEST OVERLAY</span>
<div class="catalogItemOuter 5225" style="float: left; height: 247px; visibility: visible;">
DIV CONTENTS
  </div>
</body>
```